# Is the shape of the slope in the background related to that in the foreground?

Tags: ski-safari

Now and then when I play Ski Safari (and I can pull my eyes away from the right side of the screen) I notice that the slope in the background seems to resemble the shape of the slope I'm actually skiing over.

[image: Screenshot]

Can I use this to predict upcoming hills and drops, or is it just a randomly generated coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be an exact duplicate of the slope that you are on, but it is a very good indicator, and way to preview what is coming up almost all of the time.

Once you notice this, it's hard not to watch it a lot of the time. That being said, you have to be careful of paying attention to it all the time, as it doesn't have any of the obstacles that you'll encounter on the slope you're on (signs, buildings, rocks, etc.)

**Update:** This answer only applies to the original map (Penguin Peaks). The newer map, Howling Hills, doesn't seem to have a similar background to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I found a use for it. When you are riding a cart with reindeers, sometimes you will find yourself falling vertically and there's nothing to do about it.
So here's the trick .. try to take the shape of the bacground wave then keep multiple pressing (No holding) on the screen umtil you change your position to your desired angle.